# How do i configure data labels that automatically shown in the chart using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js-datalabels

I have some problems in configuring the data labels. I wanted to show its value, but it seems that these data labels cannot be changed nor be deleted as you can see in the image attached that I circled yellow, that's the data label that cannot be changed. I have tried every possible way to change or delete it but it is still there and I don't know why.

[Bar-line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJHGW.png)

Please help me. This is the function for generating this chart:

```
        function renderChart() {
            // var ctx = document.getElementById('rocsChart').getContext('2d');
        
            let data = {
                labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Agt', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Des'],
                datasets: [{
                        label: 'ROCS',
                        // type: 'bar',
                        data: [-3971030560.1713, -3658191029.3873, -7636333358.9906, 2550158674.6845],
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)',
                        yAxisID: 'test1'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'ROCS%',
                        type: 'line',
                        data: [-13, -12, -26, -8],
                        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        fill: false,
                        yAxisID: 'test2'
                    }
                ]

            };
        
            const options = {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        id: 'test1',
                        type: 'linear',
                        position: 'left',
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                return value;
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        id: 'test2',
                        type: 'linear',
                        position: 'right',
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                return value;
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                },
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        align: 'end',
                        anchor: 'end',        
                        backgroundColor: function(context) {
                            return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
                        },
                        borderRadius: 4,
                        color: 'white',
                        formatter: function(value, context) {
                            return value;
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            };
```

For added context, this is the plugins ive been using:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-title"></script>
```

Thank you in advance.

I expecting that the data labels can be changed to the data values

Comment: There are some issues with your cdn includes: you added chart.js twice: the first is to version 3.7 and then the recommended one for the latest version; also, the title plugin should not be included any longer. Then, your scale options correspond to version2, you get an error message. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/kfpeg1b9/) a version of your code that corrects those issues; then you can start modifying/hiding the data labels which are not readable now - you may do that in the `datalabels.formatter` function [docs](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html#formatting)